# pandas.DataFrame's binary operators permute index order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

The binary operators in `pandas.DataFrame`, such as the [`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) greater than operator, seem to permute the DataFrame's index/columns in undesirable ways.  The issue seems to be that it union's together mismatched indices

> Mismatched indices will be unioned together. NaN values are considered
> different (i.e. NaN != NaN).

and that [`pd.Index.union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) (which I assume is called internally by the binary operators) sorts the indices by default.  Yet this behavior is undesirable for many (most?) applications of the binary operator and there does not appear to be a clean way to override it.

### Example

Here is an example to demonstrate.  Setting up the data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'volume': [1, 2, 3],
                   'cost': [250, 150, 100],
                   'revenue': [100, 250, 300]},
                  index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
thresh = pd.Series({'volume': 2, 'cost': 125, 'revenue': 200})
```

and printing it:

```
print(df)
   volume  cost  revenue
A       1   250      100
B       2   150      250
C       3   100      300

print(thresh)
volume       2
cost       125
revenue    200
dtype: int64
```

Since the indices of the DataFrame and Series match exactly (including order), the binary operator preserves order:

```
print(df.gt(thresh, axis=1))   # preserves column order
   volume   cost  revenue
A   False   True    False
B   False   True     True
C    True  False     True
```

What happens when we apply the binary operator with a Series whose indices (i) do not match the DataFrame order, and (ii) are not sorted?

```
thresh_perm = thresh.loc[['revenue', 'volume', 'cost']]
print(df.gt(thresh_perm, axis=1))
    cost  revenue  volume
A   True    False   False
B   True     True    True
C  False     True    True
```

The output column order matches neither the input DataFrame column order nor the Series index order.  Instead it is sorted by string name.

### Conclusion

Is my analysis correct (i.e., that pandas binary operators always sort the indices)?  What is the best way to fix this?  Ideally the binary operators would have an option that controls output order, such as:

```
df.gt(thresh_perm, axis=1, sort=False)  # desired call; code does not work
```

Since `pandas.Index.union` has a sort [option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) I think it makes sense for binary operators to be able to pass the option through.

For now, the best option seems to be to manually restore the column order:

```
print(df.gt(thresh_perm, axis=1).loc[:, df.columns])
   volume   cost  revenue
A   False   True    False
B   False   True     True
C    True  False     True
```

Comment: It sounds like `.loc[:, df.columns]` shouldn't be that bad of a fix.

Comment: It's okay.  But problematic for variables with long names, and requires a comment to explain.